# Ternary if Condition

Tags: javascript

I have this if condition, what is the equivalent of this on Ternary condition?

```
if(status === 'Active'){
    return Active
}
if(status === 'InActive'){
   return InActive
}
else{
   return Suspended
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: You'll have to nest the conditional statement, which you should never do because it makes your code less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is something like this

```
return status == 'Active' ? Active : status === 'InActive' ? InActive : Suspended
```

The long answer starts with a question - why not enjoying the full power of `javascript`?

For instance - one can perform the following instead

```
const handlers = {
 'Active': active,
 'InActive': inactive,
 'Suspended': 'some other value'
}

return handlers[status]
```

Using this pattern is also usable for invoking functions and lots of cool other stuff. Keep in mind

Comment: "Suspended" should be the fallback value for all inputs not present in the object's keys. You probably want: `return handlers[status] || 'Suspended'`

Answer (score 1):

can you try the code below

```
var state=status=='Aktive'?Aktive:status=='inActive'?Inavtive:Suspended
return state
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return {'Active': Active, 'InActive' : InActive}[status] || Suspended
```

Extendable alternative

Remove the `() =>` from the replies and suspended functions and the `()` from `Suspended)());` if you just want to return text and not execute something

```js
const replies = {
  'Active': () => "Status is active",
  'InActive': () => "Status is inactive",
}
const Suspended = () => "Status is Suspended";

const show = status => console.log((replies[status] || Suspended)());


show('Active')
show('InActive')
show('Something else')
```